# Java: calculating velocity of a skydiver

Tags: java, recursion

In Java, I am trying to implement the following equation for calculating the current velocity of a skydiver not neglecting air resistance.

> v(t) = v(t-∆t) + (g - [(drag x crossArea x airDensity) / (2*mass)] *
>   v[(t-∆t)^2] ) * (∆t)

My problem is that I am not sure how to translate "v(t - ∆t)" into a code. Right now I have this method below, where as you can see I am using the method within itself to find the previous velocity. This has continued to result in a stack overflow error message, understandably.

> (timeStep = ∆t)

```
public double calculateVelocity(double time){
    double velocity;
        velocity = calculateVelocity(time - timeStep)
                + (acceleration - ((drag * crossArea * airDensity)
                / (2 * massOfPerson))
                * (calculateVelocity(time - timeStep)*(time * timeStep)))
                * timeStep;
    }
    return velocity;        
}
```

I am calling the above method in the method below. Assuming that the ending time = an int, will be the user input but written this way to be dynamic.

```
public void assignVelocitytoArrays(){
    double currentTime = 0;     
    while(currentTime <= endingTime){
        this.vFinal = calculateVelocity(currentTime);
        currentTime += timeStep;
    }
}
```

I would like to figure this out on my own, could someone give me a general direction? Is using a method within itself the right idea or am I completely off track?

Comment: What is your stop condition/base case? Using a method within itself is called recursion and requires some form of a base case to stop itself from endlessly calling itself which is what is causing the StackOverflowException

Comment: I edited my question to show the method I am calling the calculateVelocity method in. Is this what you mean by a base case, or do you mean something like having the [v(0) = acceleration] be the break?

Comment: The first thing your calculateVelocity method does is call calculateVelocity method again. Therefore it will never stop continously calling the method no matter what it is passing in. There would need to be some sort of control statement surrounding the recursive call. For example `if (time - timeStep > 0) { calculateVelocity(time - timeStep) + the rest of the code } else return velocity;` (I don't know the math so that may make no sense mathematically but its just an example).

Comment: Removed `velocity` tag. It is for the [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) framework, not for *speed*

Comment: Shouldn't it be `calculateVelocity((time - timeStep)*(time - timeStep))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you want to implement is the recursive representation of a sequence, mathematiacally speaking.

Recursive sequences need a starting point, e.g.

> v(0) = 0 (because a negative time does not make sense)

and a rule to calculate the next elements, e.g.

> v(t) = v(t-∆t) + (g - [(drag x crossArea x airDensity) / (2*mass)] * v[(t-∆t)^2] ) * (∆t)

(btw: are you sure it has to be v([t-∆t]^2) instead of v([t-∆t])^2?)

So your approach to use recursion (calling a function within itself) to calculate a recursive sequence is correct.

In your implementation, you only forgot one detail: the starting point. How should your program know that v(0) is not defined be the rule, but by a definite value? So you must include it:

```
if(input value == starting point){
     return starting point
}
else{
    follow the rule
}
```

---

On a side note: you seem to be creating an ascending array of velocities. It would make sense to use the already calculated values in the array instead of recursion, so you don't have to calculate every step again and again.

This only works if you did indeed make a mistake in the rule.

```
double[] v = new double[maxTime/timeStep];
v[0] = 0; //starting point
for(int t = 1; t < maxSteps; t++){
    v[t] = v[t-1] + (g - [(drag x crossArea x airDensity) / (2*mass)] * v[t-1]^2 ) * (∆t)
}
```

Comment: I think you may be right by making a mistake in the rule, I am able to successfully use arrays as a substitute and I am getting the correct values!